# How to make roles in django that has different tasks based on the roles?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

im kinda new to django but i've tried using django once or twice. However, this is my first time implementing roles in django. So the case is, let's say that i have 2 roles (Manager, Normal User) and lets say 3 department. For the manager, I wanted them to can see all of the dashboard of the company. For the normal user, i wanted them to can see their own department dashboard and couldn't access to any other dashboard other than their own. For example, a Normal User from Finance department could only access Finance Department Dashboard and could not access like Sales Department and Operational Department.

I need some clues to make the roles, I've seen the django admin site where you can add some user or group. I tried looking at the documentation but it got me confused and lost. Maybe perharps I could get some hints or description that could lead me to understand how it works?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Django admin permissions is related to each Django model you have, if You want to use Django admin panel for that you can use groups and permissions, create a group for example "sales" add permissions to it (view, edit, delete, post) or some of them. After that you can assign this group permission for each user from admin panel or you can write a custom code to add some users to it by default depends on you're logic

Or You can use permissions in Django template, You need to create a permission logic in code and use it as a filter in Django template

for more information you can check this [example](https://www.scaler.com/topics/django/permissions-in-django/)